# How to perform component level automation testing android and ios app?

Tags: testing, xamarin.forms, automated-tests, appium

I am using Appium to write the automation script. I am able perform the test using  automation appium but i have no idea how component level automated test is performed for android/iOS app. Is it possible to use appium to test at component level. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. I am testing xamarin form app

Answer (score 3):

Appium is black box testing tool, which relies mostly on the application user interface: it is good for e2e testing, but I don't see how it can be used for component level testing - you need a grey-box testing tool with direct access to your components invocation.

You can test your app on component level using [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/) on Android and [XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest) on iOS

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you please suggest me any link or tool that can be used for component level test?

Comment: I updated answer to have links for both tools. Good luck!